# AJAX Font from origin and Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX example (from W3Schools) I'm trying to run on my server:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q=1?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Sophia</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP (getuser.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

// connect to db

$sql="SELECT * FROM names WHERE first = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($web_dbi, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($web_dbi));

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>grad year</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['gradyear'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting two errors on console. First, upon loading the page:

> Font from origin 'url1' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin
>   Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'url2' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Then, when I select an option value from the drop-down the console get caught up at "xmlhttp.send();" with the message:

> GET (url.getuser.php?q=1) 404 (Not Found)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well sounds like you are making a cross domain request. You can not call from one domain to another if the other domain does not have the correct CORS headers.

Comment: It also sounds like `getuser.php` is returning a 404, meaning it's not where you think it is

Comment: Are you running the page from `http://...` or `file://...`?

Comment: http:// ... I'm also utilizing Wordpress ...

Comment: is the php url really `getuser.php?q=1?q=`

Comment: The AJAX call to `getuser.php` will work only if both the html and the php files are on the same location/directory. They're probably not, and that's why you're getting the 404 error